# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize Collection

Tags: c#, json.net

A third party vendor has a series of endpoints I am consuming, they have the following structure:

```
[
     {
          "Id" : 117,
          "Name" : "Example"
     },

     {
          "Id" : 118,
          "Name" : "Sample"
     },
]
```

I created an object structure:

```
public class RootObject<TType>
{
     public TType[] ApiModels { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But when I go to deserialize I do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject<Sample[]>>(...);
```

I receive an error cannot deserialize the current JSON array?  Why?  If I do dynamic I can traverse fine, I assume I'm doing something stupid.

**Update Error:**

> One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type  because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements
>   a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.)

Comment: Is that the entire error message?  What is the exact string value that gets passed to  DeserializeObject?   Any more info you can provide?

Comment: Am not sure if the above has a typo.. Your class is named `sample`, whilst your deserialize statement has `example` in it? Also your array in the `RootType` is named `Type[]` and it shoudl be `Sample[]`

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample[]>(...);`  You have an array of the `Sample` object.  You don't have an object with an `ApiModels` property containing an array of `Sample` objects.

Comment: I fixed all the typos and added the full error sorry Amy, Rory, and Jaya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON arrays correspond to `List<T>` in C#, so instead of serialising to `RootObject<Sample[]>`, you should serialise to `List<Sample>`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(...);
```

Using `RootObject<Sample[]>` here is wrong because:

- your JSON's root is an array, not an object
- `RootObject<Sample[]>` would have a `ApiModels` property of type `Samples[][]`, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Lots of folks don't bother.  I'm glad Greg did.  Not just "credit deserved" ... but it's important for "resolved" questions to be marked as such.  Thank you, Greg!

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for explanation, I assumed it was trivial.  I forgot the top layer is irrelevant.